# First line in the TextView in Scroll view is hidden

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I'm using TextView inside ScrollView but in long Text I noticed that the first line is hidden and I can't scroll up to see it as shown in the following Screenshot

[image]

This is my layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/tip_details_ll"
android:background = "#c8d26a">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:visibility="gone"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconImg"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTxt"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Healthy Tips"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4f4f4f"
        android:layout_margin="5dip" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/closeBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="2dip" >

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>



<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dip"        
    android:background="@drawable/seperator" >
</View>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomShadow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topShadow" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tips"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_weight="1.33"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollbars = "vertical"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="In order to succeed, your desire for success should be greater than your fear of failure.In order to succeed, your desire for success should be greater than your fear of failure"
            android:textColor="#4f4f4f"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todayDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="lucida grande"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Mon, 16 Dec 2013"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"        
    android:background="@drawable/seperator" >
</View>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/previous_tip_rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/previous_tip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/previous_button"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/share_rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/share_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/star"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/star_off"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/next_tip_rl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_tip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/next_button"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"        
    android:background="@drawable/seperator" >
</View>

<Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_dismiss"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:text="dismiss"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

How to solve this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with your XML. Here's a quick summary and some corrected code:

- You have `android:layout_alignParentTop` within a `LinearLayout` element, which does nothing. These should only be in children of `RelativeLayout`s
- `android:textSize` should always use `sp` units, instead of `dp` (see [Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) for details)
- You appear to have an unnecessary `RelativeLayout` called `android:id="@+id/closeBtn"`, not sure what you are using it for since it's empty
- You have `android:layout_above` and `layout_below` within your `ScrollView`, which once again, does nothing since it's not a child of a `RelativeLayout`
- Any children views of `LinearLayout`s where you define `android:layout_weight` to some value should have `android:layout_height="0dp"`, since the layout manager will layout the views faster and more optimally this way.

However, your specific issue with the text is due to your `TextView` and `LinearLayout` parameters within the `ScrollView`. You're using `fill_parent` for the height of the views which is not correct, you only want the height to match your content. And you have margins and gravity where they don't belong. Try this code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tips"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:text="your long text"
            android:textColor="#4f4f4f"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todayDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="lucida grande"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Mon, 16 Dec 2013"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont work with android so this is a work around, you can get an aproximate amount of characters that can be displayed without having that issue. and then if the string length is bigger than that amount just add a line jump at the start of the string;

amount= 300;

```
if string.length > amount then string = "\r\n" + string;
```

Edit: if android cuts the empty line out add a single character like '-' and then the line jump.

Comment: Dude im not into android, i was just trying to help.